# Dúvida sobre o operador MOD em PHP

Tags: php, operadores

Tenho um código `PHP` que realiza um determinado cálculo, entretanto ele esta resultando algo diferente do que eu espero, realizei os cálculos na mão e não gerou o mesmo resultado, alguém poderia me explicar o por que? O código para execução está abaixo:

```
function bsd_rand($seed) {
return function() use (&$seed) {
    return $seed = (1103515245 * $seed + 12345) % (1 << 31);
};
}

$lcg = bsd_rand(0);
echo "BSD ";
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
echo $lcg(), " ";
echo "\n";
```

O primeiro valor resulta em `12345`, mas fazendo este mesmo cálculo no papel, não resultou tal valor, observem:

```
(1103515245 * 0 + 12345) % (-2147483648) = ?
```

O resultado deveria ser `-2147471303` e não `12345`

Comment: Curti o Currying

Comment: Poderia explicar o porquê do resultado esperado ser -2147471303 e não 12345, só para entendermos melhor a sua linha de raciocínio? Em outras palavras, como é que você calculou "manualmente"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A explicação já foi dada pelo @chambelix, ao que aparenta, o operador `mod (%)` não trabalha muito bem em `PHP` para quando o "modulo" do divisor negativo (leia-se o numero sem o sinal de negativo) é maior do que o dividendo positivo... Ou vice-versa, vide testes:

```
echo (12345 % (-2147471303))."\n"; // Retorna 12345 (errado)
echo ((-2147471303) % 12345)."\n"; // Retorna -9173 (errado)
```

Para se ter uma melhor experiencia com valores negativos muito grandes, existe uma [função](http://mindspill.net/computing/web-development-notes/php/php-modulo-operator-returns-negative-numbers/) que resolve o problema:

```
function truemod($num, $mod) {
  return ($mod + ($num % $mod)) % $mod;
}

echo truemod(12345,-2147471303)."\n"; // Retorna -2147471303 (certo)
echo truemod(-2147471303,12345); // Retorna 3172 (certo)
```

---

Honestamente, acho que a função que esta usando esta um tanto quanto confusa.... eu faria dessa forma:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $numerador = (1103515245 * $i + 12345);
    $seed = truemod($numerador,-2147471303);
    echo "BSD: " . $seed . "\n";
}
echo "\n";

function truemod($num, $mod) {
  return ($mod + ($num % $mod)) % $mod;
}
```

---

Nesse caso: `&$seed` o operador `&` funciona como uma referência a variável `$seed` que foi passada pela função pai...

> /* Acho meio doido entender essa função abaixo, ou ver uma utilidade, mas ok... */

```
function bsd_rand($seed) {
    return function() use (&$seed) {
        //Retorne essa função, utilizando a mesma referencia de variável que gerou a variável $seed
    }
}
```

Em geral, o operador `& $variavel` nesse caso funciona como uma referência...

Links uteis:

[O que são referências?](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.whatare.php)

[O que as referências fazem](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.whatdo.php)

Comment: irei realizar um teste rápido em java e verificar se acontece o mesmo problema, só um minutinho.

Comment: Em java, estranhamente ele me resulta em 0.

Comment: Desculpe, errei na sintaxe, resultou tudo corretamente, mas ainda não entendi o por que deste resultado, utilizando a seed como 12345 ele não gera o mesmo resultado obtido a mão.

Comment: Na verdade, em Java só os primeiros 3 resultados são gerados conforme o software acima, mas acho que isto tem relação com aquele & na frente da seed passada como parâmetro.

Comment: @DanLucioPrada editei minha resposta com uma ideia para sua função...

Comment: mas utilizando este truemod do PHP eles me resultado algo diferente do que o esperado, eu realmente preciso da queles valores, por que em um determinado momento ele me gera 68, que é um número baixo, com este truemod ele gera valores muito grande em todos os casos, foge do contexto, eu preciso entender o que está passando na função, o por que dela esta se auto retornando, e o por que da passagem da seed como parâmetro ter um & na frente, o que ele significa. Desculpe minha insistência, sou apenas um estudante procurando respostas =D

Answer (score 0):

No o PHP o operador **%** refere-se a:

```
$a % $b Módulo  Resto de $a dividido por $b.
```

sendo que os operandos de módulo são convertidos para inteiros (removendo a parte decimal) antes de processar... ao que ainda adiciono:

```
O resto de $a % $b é negativo se $a for negativo.
```

O que coloca desde logo o resultado que deveria no seu entender impossível.

Adicionar ainda que o modulus em PHP se o primeiro operando for inferior ao segundo, então o valor do primeiro é retornado.

Comment: Certo, mas o que significa o & antes da variável seed passada como parâmetro? E o porque de ele retornar a própria função.

Comment: Significa que está a passar a variável como referência e não como valor

Comment: Digo isto, pois exato, utilizando o número positivo, obtenho o primeiro resulta de 12345, entretanto já na segunda operação o resultado não fecha, por exemplo, a seed na segunda passada do for vale o valor anterior, 12345, e realizando o calculo ele retorna -740551042, mas fazendo na mão resulta 1485236941

Comment: Ela é passada como referência? Como assim, qual valor ela está recebendo?

Comment: o que significa que está a passar o endereço dessa variável e não o seu valor se colocar um  echo "<br>",":",$seed,":"; antes do return poderá avaliar o seu valor que só pode ser "EMPTY"

Comment: Ainda não foi esclarecida totalmente, afinal meu problema ainda persiste, mesmo utilizando o módulo positivo, apenas o primeiro valor bate, realize o mesmo calculo utilizando como seed = 12345, e compare com o valor gerado pelo código.